# Want to remove '/' slashes in query when passing json in query

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my JSON string:

{"218":"7","223":["11"],"217":"4"} and the same will store in database field.

When I pass this in query for fetching record of same string then it will append "/" in query like below so it will not return me result.

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('oc_cart');
$this->db->where('option',$proption);
$this->db->get()->row();
echo $this->db->last_query();exit;

SELECT * FROM `oc_cart` WHERE `customer_id` = '4' AND `product_id` = '42' AND `option` = '{\"218\":\"7\",\"223\":[\"11\"],\"217\":\"4\"}'
```

How to stop adding slashes in string in query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well.. what's creating the query?

Comment: Ok edit and put code to create query.I am using codeignitor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the \ character with mysql query too.

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_cart` WHERE `customer_id` = '4' AND `product_id` = '42' AND `option` = replace('{\"218\":\"7\",\"223\":[\"11\"],\"217\":\"4\"}', '\\', '');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Slashes are append after query execution so your code not working.

Comment: so you are not getting desired output just because of those slashes ?

Comment: Yes becuase it is not matched with database stored string.